# RequireJS and functions

Tags: javascript, requirejs

There is a part of my `main.js` that contains functions like these:

```
function isTrue(x){...}
function resizeEditors() {...}
function updateLayout() {...}
function prettify() {...}
function setTheme(theme) {...}
function themedLayout(isDark){...}
function enablePanel(panel) {...}
function disablePanel(panel) {...}
function enableDefaultPanels() {...}
function toggleFullscreen() {...}
function toggleEditorFullscreen(selected) {...}
```

Is there a way to make these functions available to my `main.js` file's dependencies?

for example, in `editors.js` I'm using the `isTrue` function but the editors.js module can't currently find `isTrue` because it's inside the `main.js` file

```
editors.setShowPrintMargin( isTrue( settings.showPrintMargin ) );
```

---

**edit**:

how the project look like:

`main.js`:

```
require(['jquery', 'appSession', 'editors'], function ($, appSession, editors) {
    function isTrue(x){...}
    function resizeEditors() {...}
    function updateLayout() {...}
    function prettify() {...}
    function setTheme(theme) {...}
    function themedLayout(isDark){...}
    function enablePanel(panel) {...}
    function disablePanel(panel) {...}
    function enableDefaultPanels() {...}
    function toggleFullscreen() {...}
    function toggleEditorFullscreen(selected) {...}
});
```

`editors.js`:

```
define(['jquery', 'appSession'], function($, appSession){
    ...
    editors.setShowPrintMargin( isTrue( settings.showPrintMargin ) );
    ...
    return editors;
});
```

Comment: Please show us your current dependency map, and how you use require.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can return them.

```
define(function () {
    return {
        isTrue: function() {
            // Code
        },
        otherFunction: function() {
            // Code
        }
    }
});
```

Then use them ass this

```
require(["main"], function(main) {

    main.isTrue(false);

});
```

You can learn more about defining modules on the [website](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define).

Comment: is there a way to inject them in window instead of main? so that i can call them with `isTrue()` instead of `main.isTrue()`

Comment: This is a bad idea, it will pollute the global namespace. But yes, you can just add it to the window like this `window.badFunction = function() { // This is bad }`. However it would make no sense to do this when you use requirejs.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a module containing the shared/global functionality and make it a dependency of the modules that need it:

globals.js:

```
define([], function() {
    function isTrue(x){}
    // rest of functions...
    function toggleEditorFullscreen(selected) {}

    return { // return functions... };
});
```

Then to use it:

```
require(["globals", "editors"], function(globals, editors) {
    // ...
    editors.setShowPrintMargin(globals.isTrue(settings.showPrintMargin));
    // ...
});
```

Or if you wanted to use it within the editors module, you're editors.js would look like:

```
define(["globals"], function(globals) {
    // ...
    setShowPrintMargin(globals.isTrue(settings.showPrintMargin));
    // ...
});
```

Alternatively, if you really want them to be global you should be able to do:

```
window.isTrue = function(valueToCheck) {
    // implementation ...
};
```

Comment: You can do it in any file. Whenever the file/module is included/executed the functions would be added to window and thus be available globally.